# Using cmaps for scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 seperate lists of floats. 2 lists are the x and y coordinates and the frequencies list are how they should be color coordinated. I keep running into the same error when I plot the graph. I'm a bit stumped. Also, there are 5 frequencies not 3. I'm not sure if I can add more colors to my color map other than RGB.

```
data = csv.reader(file1) 
x = []
y = []
frequencies = [] 
colormap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])


for row in data : 
    x.append(float(row[0]))
    y.append(float(row[2]))
    frequencies.append(float(row[1]))

mplot.scatter(x, y, cmap = colormap[frequencies], marker = 'o', s=10)  
mplot.show()
```

the error is as follows:

> mplot.scatter(x, y, cmap = colormap[frequencies], marker = 'o', s=10)
>
> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer 
>      or boolean arrays are valid indices

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a list of color values, not a colormap. Try using c=... to set one or more single values colors.

Take a look at the documentation for more details and examples: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Aside from named colors you can also input other formats such as Hex. A list of named colors can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html

Alternatively, you can find the readily available cmaps here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html

Lastly, a higher level alternative with useful defaults is the seaborn package: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to read your csv using **pandas** library rather than csv library. So you can get each column using 'iloc'(index location of the column).  Code is developed as per your requirement.

> Code:

```
#Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read csv file as dataframe. I have loaded my sample data
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

print(df)

#load each column to x, y, frequencies respectively by selectinfg using iloc
x = df.iloc[:,0]
y = df.iloc[:,1]
frequencies = df.iloc[:,2]
colormap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])

#plot the graph
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colormap)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.show()
```

> Output:

```
     x    y  freq
0  0.2  0.4     1
1  0.4  0.6     3
2  0.5  0.9     2
```

[image]

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: The issue is that the csv file has repeating frequencies. Hence, the list could have x of one value and y of another. When color mapping that - its stating the argument is supposed to be 5 (or 3 in your case), but it is 499 (the length of the csv file).